# How to give && and || in same condition using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want  to give && and || in same condition using jquery.
My Html code is:

```
  <table>
<tr>
    <td>fruits<select id="fruits">
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <option value="1">apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
        <option value="3">mango</option>

        </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>vegitables
        <select id="vegit">
            <option value="">--select--</option>
            <option value="1">brinjal</option>
            <option value="2">tomato</option>
        <option value="3">onion</option>
        <option value="4">potato</option></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>qty<input id="qty" type="text"/>
</td>
</tr></table>
    <button >test</button>
```

I want to do the conditions:

select any one of them. ie either fruits or vegitables.
   If vegitables is selected then the qty field must entered some values.

ie, fruits OR (vegitables AND qty):

How it can be write using jquery?

SqlFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ss398m3g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ss398m3g/1/
Updated if you want to restrict fruits and veggys from being selected at the same time: http://jsfiddle.net/ss398m3g/2/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var fruitSelection = $('#fruits option:selected').val();
    var vegySelection = $('#vegit option:selected').val();
    var quantity = $('#qty').val();

    if (fruitSelection > 0 && vegySelection > 0) {
        alert("I know your supossed to eat fruits and veggys, but you can't have both here...");
    } else if (fruitSelection > 0 || (vegySelection > 0 && quantity !== '')) {
        alert("your good!");
    } else if (fruitSelection < 1 && vegySelection < 1) {
        alert("you didn't select anything boss...");
    } else {
        alert("your missing something.  maybe a quantity?");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankzzz. It is I really want. It works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first option value of fruit to empty:

```
 <option value="">--select--</option>
```

And then use:

```
$('button').click(function(){
 if( $('#fruits option:selected').val()!="" || ( $('#vegit option:selected').val()!="" &&  $("#qty ").val()!="")){
 alert("select  items")
}});
```

Alert will be fired,when either fruit is selected. or, vegetable is selected and qty input is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `||` and `&&` in you statement, but remember the parentheses. I believe this should work for you:

```
if( $('#fruits').val() != "" || ( $('#vegit').val() != '' &&  $("#qty ").val() != ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){

    if( $('#fruits option:selected').val()=="" ||  $('#vegit option:selected').val()=='' &&  $("#qty ").val()=="")

{
    alert("select  items")
}

})
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: sorry... It is not I expected. I want: If fruits selected, then it does not alerted. then if vegetables selected, qty also must  be selected.

Comment: as far as i understand is : you want that if user select fruit den no need for alert and if user selects vegetable then you require alert because quantity is needed in case of vegetable.??